# Insert multiple arrays from inputs

Tags: php, mysqli

This is var_dump from $_POST:

```
array(27) { ["name"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(8) "desktops" [1]=> string(7) "laptops" } ["type"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(7) "WorkPro" [1]=> string(8) "WorkPlus" } ["hdd"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(0) "" [1]=> string(0) "" } ["monitor"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(0) "" [1]=> string(0) "" } ["processor"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(0) "" [1]=> string(0) "" } ["ram"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(0) "" [1]=> string(0) "" } ["net"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(0) "" [1]=> string(0) "" } ["battery"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(0) "" [1]=> string(0) "" } ["burner"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(0) "" [1]=> string(0) "" } ["keyboard"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(0) "" [1]=> string(0) "" } ["os"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(0) "" [1]=> string(0) "" } ["office"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(0) "" [1]=> string(0) "" } ["antivirus"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(0) "" [1]=> string(0) "" } ["extra_1"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(0) "" [1]=> string(0) "" } ["extra_2"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(0) "" [1]=> string(0) "" } ["extra_3"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(0) "" [1]=> string(0) "" } ["extra_4"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(0) "" [1]=> string(0) "" } ["extra_5"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(0) "" [1]=> string(0) "" } ["extra_6"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(0) "" [1]=> string(0) "" } ["description"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(0) "" [1]=> string(0) "" } ["lapse"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(0) "" [1]=> string(0) "" } ["period"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(3) "mes" [1]=> string(3) "mes" } ["quantity"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(0) "" [1]=> string(0) "" } ["price"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(0) "" [1]=> string(0) "" } ["iva"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(4) "true" [1]=> string(4) "true" } ["total_show"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(4) "true" [1]=> string(4) "true" } ["save"]=> string(4) "true" }
```

I have something like that but i don't know how insert on database.

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
        $data[$key] = $value;
        $keys[] = $key;
    }

    for ($i=0; $i < count($data); $i++) { 
        print_r($data[$keys[$i]]);
    }
```

i get this:

```
Array ( [0] => desktops [1] => laptops ) Array ( [0] => [1] => ) Array ( [0] => [1] => ) Array ( [0] => [1] => ) Array ( [0] => [1] => ) Array ( [0] => [1] => ) Array ( [0] => [1] => ) Array ( [0] => [1] => ) Array ( [0] => [1] => ) Array ( [0] => [1] => ) Array ( [0] => [1] => ) Array ( [0] => [1] => ) Array ( [0] => [1] => ) Array ( [0] => [1] => ) Array ( [0] => [1] => ) Array ( [0] => [1] => ) Array ( [0] => [1] => ) Array ( [0] => [1] => ) Array ( [0] => [1] => ) Array ( [0] => [1] => ) Array ( [0] => [1] => ) Array ( [0] => mes [1] => mes ) Array ( [0] => [1] => ) Array ( [0] => [1] => ) Array ( [0] => true [1] => true ) Array ( [0] => true [1] => true )
```

i need with this data make two insert one for desktops y other for laptops and so.

Something like this:

```
 INSERT INTO $table ($keys) VALUES ($values[0]), ($values[1]);
```

before i had something like this:

```
for ( $i=0; $i < count($_POST['name']) ; $i++ ){
 $name = DB::esc($_POST['name'][$i]);
 $type = DB::esc($_POST['type'][$i]);
 $hdd = DB::esc($_POST['hdd'][$i]);

 $query = DB::query("INSERT INTO product VALUES($name,$type,$hdd)");
}
```

it's work but i need that is dynamic.

Comment: What do you exactly want to save at your database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a foreach to get the keys:

```
$desktop = array();
$laptop = array();
$keys = array();
foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
    $desktop[] = $value[0];
    $laptop[] = $value[1];
    $keys[] = $key;
}

$fields = implode(', ', $keys);
$desktopQ = implode(', ', $desktop);
$laptopQ = implode(', ', $laptop);


$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "db");

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

/* Insert into database */
if (mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO $table ($fields) VALUES ($desktopQ) ") === TRUE) {
    printf("YEAH!  Insertion success for Desktops!.\n");
}

/* Insert into database */
if (mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO $table ($fields) VALUES ($laptopQ) ") === TRUE) {
    printf("YEAH!  Insertion success for Laptops!.\n");
}
```

Comment: yes i know, but how split these arrays and insert into database.

Comment: this is not the problem. i don't know is how split the array for insert something like that INSERT INTO $table ($keys) VALUES ($values[0]), ($values[1]);

Comment: It looks like you have an array `$data` that maps keys to an array with 2 elements.  I'm assuming the first element is for desktop, and the other is for laptop?

Comment: So $keys contains your column names?

Comment: What does `var_dump($_POST)` output?

Comment: Array with all data from form inputs that each input is array something like that <input name="type[]">

Comment: Could you post the result of the dump in your question?

Comment: Cool, I've made the changes.

Comment: these fields can be more or sometimes just one. any solution. because can't find it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need something like this:

You have your data which you get them from input $_POST fields.

```
$data = array('fname' => $_POST['fname'], 'lname' => $_POST['lname']);
```

Then you need to implode them like this:

```
$values = '\'' . implode('\', \'', $data) . '\'';
$fields = implode(', ', array_keys($data));
```

And at the end you can insert them into database like this:

```
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "user", "pass", "db");

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) 
{
    printf("Failed!", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

if (mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO $table ($fields) VALUES ($values) ") === TRUE) 
{
    printf("Success!");
}
```

Comment: Try to find solution for multidimensional array for your own. I give you some basic example, and you can continue from this point.